# GPIO input connected to garage door button

Tags: raspberry-pi, isolation, gpio, circuit-protection

I know there are other GPIO / Garage door related questions, but this is not a duplicate- I need to read the status of the garage door button, not a garage door sensor.

I would like to connect the garage door's button to a GPIO input on my Pi. I want to be able to trigger actions when someone pushes the button. I am able to read the status of a basic switch using [this circuit](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/buttons_and_switches/) I found. My concern is that when I connect a volt meter across the garage door button I see over 16 volts (presumably to drive the LED in the button?). I am concerned that if I connect my switch reading GPIO input circuit to the button, that 16 volts could fry my Pi. How can I read whether the button is open or closed, but protect my Pi from the voltage on the line?

I do also have a garage door magnetic switch sensor that I can read fine with my GPIO circuit, but my requirements include knowing when the button is pushed- not just whether the door is open or closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that you are looking for an optocoupler?

Comment: I think it is.  Just found that...